# Add a dot to the REGEX

Tags: regex, adduser

I have tried to add a dot to the current REGEX in the `/etc/adduser.conf` file on Ubuntu 16.10 but it doesn't seem to save as I cannot add a user that has a username of: `mediasvr.adm`

Current REGEX is: `REGEX"^[a-z][-a-z0-9.]*\$"`

Answer (score 3):

Your expression as is **requires** usernames to end with a dollar sign `\$`.  Remove the escape (backslash) to match *end of line* `$` instead:

```
"^[a-z][-a-z0-9.]*$"
```

Comment: @Zanna not in  `[...]`. There it's a plain `.`

Comment: Ah, that's tricky. Ubuntu 20 has that extra backslash in the example `NAME_REGEX` in the default `/etc/adduser.conf` file, which is really misleading. (Especially since the config file syntax looks a lot like bash, and in bash that extra backslash would be totally appropriate as it would simply stop the shell from interpreting the $ as an environment variable, and the `\\` wouldn't show up in the final Regex.) Looks like there's been a bug report about this for 6 years now and it's never been fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adduser/+bug/1387825